# Evaluate/MATCH function in VBA not working when comparing multiple criteria

Tags: excel, vba, match

I've scoured the internet for a solution to this issue.

I have lists that should match and need to be compared reciprocally. I need to compare 5 or so different variables within each row, then using the MATCH function, would identify the first matching row which is then deleted. I will then loop through the list until there are remaining entries that aren't deleted. The reason I need to delete is because there may be multiple matches within each list, but if there are 3 in one list and 4 in another, I would need the 4th (extra) entry to be identified.

Please critique the code I have below, I have yet to create the loop as I think that will be the easy part once I have gotten the MATCH function to work accurately. The standard CSE formula works within the sheet, but I need VBA for the looping ability. Thanks.

I try to verify the value of RowDelete with the msgbox, and return a run-time error 13: "type mismatch". I also tried use the WATCH window to see what result get passed but the actual formula itself doesn't seem to work.

EDIT: This code returns a run-time error '13': type mismatch. I cannot resolve it. I would just like to know what I can do to pass Formula a result I can use (in this instance the first result is row 62). After that I will be able to do everything on my own.

```
Sub DeleteMatches2()

    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim Direction As String
    Dim OrderType As String
    Dim Amount As String
    Dim CCY As String
    Dim Rate As String

    Dim RowCt As Long
    Dim Formula As Integer

    Dim iRow As Long

    Dim colNum As Integer

    Dim RowDelete As Long

    Set Ws = Sheets("KOOLTRA RAW")

    With Ws
        RowCt = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 11).End(xlUp).Row - 1

        For iRow = 2 To RowCt

            Direction = .Cells(iRow, "K").Value
            OrderType = .Cells(iRow, "L").Value
            Amount = .Cells(iRow, "M").Value
            CCY = .Cells(iRow, "N").Value
            Rate = .Cells(iRow, "P").Value

            Formula = Evaluate("MATCH(1,(""" & OrderType & """ = B:B)*(""" & Direction & """ = C:C)*(""" & Amount & """ = D:D)*(""" & CCY & """ = E:E)*(""" & Rate & """ = H:H),0)")
            MsgBox Formula

            Exit For

        Next iRow
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I have commented your code in the hope that my comments will help you improve it.

```
Sub DeleteMatches()

    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim Direction As Variant
    Dim OrderType As Variant
    Dim Amount As Variant
    Dim CCY As Variant
    Dim Rate As Variant
    Dim RowCt As Long                       ' rows and columns should be of Long type
    Dim Formula As Variant
    Dim iRow As Long
    Dim colNum As Long
    Dim RowDelete As Long

    Set Ws = Sheets("Example")                      ' don't "select" anything

    With Ws
        ' creating variable for toral rows to cycle through:-
        ' you aren't "creating" a variable.
        ' RowCt is the variable and you are assigning a value to it.
        RowCt = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 11).End(xlUp).Row - 1

        For iRow = 2 To RowCt                       ' loop through all rows
            ' assigning a Range to a Variant (Direction etc) assigns the
            ' Range object to the variant. I have modified the code
            ' to assign the specified cell's value to the variant.
            ' A Variant can be anything. It would be better if you
            ' would declare your variables as String or Double or Integer or Long.
            Direction = .Cells(iRow, "K").Value     ' Range("K" & iRow)
            OrderType = .Cells(iRow, "L").Value     ' Range("L" & iRow)
            Amount = .Cells(iRow, "M").Value        ' Range("M" & iRow)
            CCY = .Cells(iRow, "N").Value           ' Range("N" & iRow)
            Rate = .Cells(iRow, "P").Value          ' Range("P" & iRow)

            ' Formula is a property of the Range object.
            ' use like .Cells(iRow, "X").Formula = "MATCH(1,((B:B="" & OrderType & "") ......
'            Formula = "MATCH(1,((B:B="" & OrderType & "")*(C:C="" & Direction & "")*(D:D="" & Amount & "")*(E:E="" & CCY& "")*(H:H="" & Rate & "")),0)"
            ' To set a formula, you need to enter the = sign, like
            ' .Cells(iRow, "X").Formula = " = MATCH(1 ...
            ' it is best that you test the formula on the worksheet
            ' before attempting to let VBA write it to a cell.
            ' Your above formula looks like nothing Excel would be able to execute.

            ' Please read up on how to use the Evaluate function.
            ' It can't do what you appear to expect it to do.
'            RowDelete = Evaluate(Formula)

            MsgBox RowDelete

            'colNum = Application.Match(1,((B1:B2=OrderType)*(C1:C2=Direction)*(D:D=Amount)*(E:E=CCY)*(H:H=Rate)),0)
            ' I think it is the better idea to let VBA execute the MATCH function
            ' rather than writing the formula to the worksheet.
            ' However, your "code" has no similarity with what MATCH can do.
            ' Read up on how to use the the MATCH function correctly.
            ' When executed by VBA it needs the same syntax as when called from the worksheet.


            'Formula = "MATCH(1,((B:B=OrderType)*(C:C=Direction)*(D:D=Amount)*(E:E=CCY)*(H:H=Rate)),0)"
            'Formula = "MATCH(1,((B:B=L2)*(C:C=K2)*(D:D=M2)*(E:E=N2)*(H:H=P2)),0)"
            'colNum = Worksheets("Example").Evaluate("MATCH(1,((B:B=OrderType)*(C:C=Direction)*(D:D=Amount)*(E:E=CCY)*(H:H=Rate)),0)")

            Exit For            ' stop the loop here during testing
                                ' remove this stop after your code works
        Next iRow
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, I appreciate you trying to get me to learn independently - I have probably trawled through hundreds of threads on using Application.Match and Evaluate etc. I did not just put those in blindly. The original code had just a few examples of others attempts I had made, which is why they were commented.

If you could please provide me an overt solution I would appreciate it - this issue is driving me nuts.

Comment: If you would overtly state your intention I shall probably be happy to supply you a workable solution. Problem is that you can't post a workbook here. You may not be able to show your data and, hence, your intention for manipulating them. Try a site like TeachExcel.com

Comment: I've edited my original post with your updated code - I literally just need to get the Formula/MATCH function to work. I have gotten it to work within the sheet directly, but not in VBA. I have tried very hard to resolve this on my own (which I have done many times before) but am stumped on this one.

Comment: OK. To get you started, when you write a formula to a cell, assign the formula to the Formula property. Start the formula with an = sign, like .Formula = "=EVALUATE(MATCH..." If you need more help please provide the formula you wish to enter in plain text as you say it works for you in the worksheet. I can't see your intention from faulty code.

Comment: {=MATCH(1,((B:B=L2)*(C:C=K2)*(D:D=M2)*(E:E=N2)*(H:H=P2)),0)}

Returns the correct row number, which I then plan to delete and loop through until undeleted rows = unmatched outputs